# Criar um Agente/Job do Oracle para o PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, oracle, scheduler, oracle10g

Gostaria de saber se é possível criar um agente/job no Oracle para consultar os dados de uma determinada tabela e inserir os dados desta tabela para numa outra tabela que está no PostgreSQL.

Ou se consigo através do PGAgent do PostgreSQL criar um job para realizar a consulta na tabela do Oracle e inserir os dados na tabela do PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em `Postgres`, você pode escrever uma *stored procedure* usando a linguagem [`PL/Python`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/plpython.html) capaz de se conectar em um banco `Oracle`, possibilitando o intercâmbio de dados, veja só:

```
CREATE FUNCTION oracle_foobar()
RETURNS SETOF tb_foobar AS
$BODY$
  import cx_Oracle

  conn = cx_Oracle.connect('usuario/senha@servidor_oracle/database')
  cur = conn.cursor()

  cur.execute('select * from tb_foobar')
  ret = cur[:]

  cur.close()
  conn.close()

  return ret;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpythonu;
```

Uma vez com a função `oracle_foobar()` criada, você pode usa-lá para extrair os dados de um banco de dados `Oracle` (`tb_foobar`) e inserí-las em um banco de dados `Postgres` (`tb_xpto`), por exemplo:

```
INSERT INTO tb_xpto ( a, b, c )
(SELECT a, b, c FROM oracle_foobar() WHERE c = 3);
```

No `Postgres` você pode usar o [`pg_cron`](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron) para executar a função de forma agendada.

Todos os dias, às `10:00am`, por exemplo:

```
SELECT cron.schedule('0 10 * * *', $$INSERT INTO tb_xpto ( a, b, c )(SELECT a, b, c FROM oracle_foobar() WHERE c = 3);$$ );
```

Comment: Lacobus, primeiramente muito obrigado pelo feedback. Vou tentar implementar a solução.

Comment: Baixei a última versão do Python 3.6.5, mas não estou conseguindo importar o módulo cx_Oracle no interpretador Python.

--------------
Traceback <most recent call last>
File "<stdin>", line1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cx_Oracle'
--------------